# Redirect users to unauthorized page (temp solution)

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, .net-5

I have a basic .net5 (asp.net mvc core) application that does not use Identity. However, I use Windows Autentication to recognize users.

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

and

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
```

I have a table `MyUsers`, and there is a `Login` column. I want that any user that is not in the `MyUsers` (Login does not fit) table to be redirected to a custom page say, `/Views/UnAuthorised`.

I use this as **temporary solution** until I will implement the Indentity, but in the actual version I need just to redirect all other users to a page, as a **quickfix**.

I try to redirect "unrecognized" users to 401:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var user = _userService.GetCurrentUser();
    if (user == null)
        return Unauthorized();

    return View();
}
```

that gives me a blank page... if GetCurrentUser returns null.

Here is my UserResolverService:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<MyUser> GetCurrentUserAsync()
{
    UserGeobase currentUser;
    var currentSessionUser = _sessionService.GetCurrentUser();

    if (currentSessionUser != null)
    {
        currentUser = _repository.GetById<MyUser>(currentSessionUser.Id);
        if (currentUser != null)
            return currentUser;
    }

    var name = (_context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Split('\\')[1]; // split 'DOMAIN\UserLogin'
    currentUser = _repository.SingleOrDefault(new MyUserByUsernameSpecification(name));

    if (currentUser is null)
    {
        // if not found, redirect to unauthorized page
        // ??
        // ??
    }
    else
    {
        currentUser.ConnectionDate = DateTime.Now;
        await _repository.UpdateAsync(currentUser);
    }

    _sessionService.SetCurrentUser(currentUser.Id, currentUser.UserName);
    return currentUser;
}
```

Questions:

1. How to redirect 401 to a custom view?
2. How to check this for all the controllers, not only Home/Index

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use RedirectAction() to redirect to the required page.

Comment: I see but where to implement that... I mean, a middleware something that will check that..

Comment: I think we need to redirect such unauthorized users to the UnAuthorised page from the presentation layer itself. Something like LoginPage -> Calls UserResolverService and redirects to UnAuthorised page if service returns null as currentUser.

Comment: I suppose i need to use a middleware that will redirect all unrecognized users to a page

Comment: If you want to use middleware,you can refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0),It should be noted that the middleware will be triggered before the actions.

Answer (score 0):

you are seeing a blank page because you are not returning any `View` but something else like `Ok`, `BadRequest` etc.

if you want to redirect to another view based on any decision then use `return View("MyView", model); // model is optional`

so your code should look like below.

```
if(user == null)
{
    return View("MyView", model);
}
```

you can also use `return RedirectToAction("MyView");`